# jQuery Draggable Helper stop automatic removal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, helper

I've having a problem where I am using the jQuery ui draggable functionality with the helper option( helper: 'clone' ) - it all works great but when you stop dragging the helper is being removed and I really need it to stay in the DOM. Any help as to how to keep it in the DOM much appreciated!!

I've tried adding "stop" function with the following:

event.preventDefault();

that prevents the helper to be removed but the dragging functionality no longer works.

Here is the full code I have:

```
$( "#draggable" ).width(faceWidth).height(faceHeight).draggable({
                helper : getHelper,
                containment: "#containment-wrapper",
                scroll: false,
                revert: 'invalid',
                cursor: 'move',

                drag: function(event, ui) {
                    var position = ui.helper.position();
                    $('.face').css('top', position.top).css('left',position.left);
                    draggableLeft = position.left;
                    draggableTop = position.top;
                },
                stop: function( e, ui ) {
                    // e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

UPDATE: here is the html code:

```
<div id="image">
     <div class="player">
         <img src="images/app/player.png" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div class="face">
         <img src="images/app/face.jpg" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div id="draggable"></div>
     <div id="resizable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post the html code also?

Comment: I have faced the same issue with sortable. Hence I'm removing helper manually in stop event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            helper : "clone"
});
$( "body" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.helper).removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging');
        var newDiv = $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging');
        $(this).append(newDiv);
  }  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jje3H/

And if you want to make subsequent clones draggable as well then take a look at this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jje3H/1/

Or if you just want to be able to move subsequent clones then:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jje3H/2/